# LDAP Login is converting system user to website user in ERPNext

Tags: ldap, erpnext

I have integrated LDAP to enable AD users to login to ERPNext. I have mapped AD user group to ERPNext Roles. Default user type is set to 'System User', but when an user logs into ERPNext with AD credentials, he is converted to website user in ERPNext and he is not able to access desk. Is there some setting I am missing?

When user logs in to ERPNext with LDAP credentials, he should remain system user and able to access ERPNext based on the role he is assigned to.